# Ubuntu install pkg problem

Tags: 14.04, server

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-54-gener
ic_3.13.0-54.91_amd64.deb --install
(Reading database ... 366465 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic_3.13.0-54.91_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic (3.13.0-54.91) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-54-gen
eric_3.13.0-54.91_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic' to '/boot/vml
inuz-3.13.0-54-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-54-generic /boo
t/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-54-generic /boot
/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic
dpkg: error processing archive --install (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic_3.13.0-54.91_amd64.deb
 --install
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you:

```
cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic' to 
'/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic.dpkg-new': 
failed to write (No space left on device)
```

You have insufficient free disk space on `/boot`.

**WARNING** Do not simply delete files in `/boot`. See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607594/why-is-it-unsafe-to-delete-old-kernels/607699#607699)
for why.