# At Login says security update and package upgrade available but unable to install

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

When i login i see

```
8 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

> When i try

```
apt-get update

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease      
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease    
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Fetched 94.5 kB in 0s (161 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
```

> When i try

```
apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic but it is not installed
Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

> If i try **apt-get -f install** as suggested above that also fails

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-21 linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-22
  linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/18.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 55.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 225185 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic_4.4.0-31.50_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic (4.4.0-31.50) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic_4.4.0-31.50_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic_4.4.0-31.50_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Based on Comments

```
-----------------
Filesystem                 1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1                     240972   229789         0 100% /boot
```

Comment: "No spacd left on device" = full disk. Free up some space.

Comment: I think you might be right, my /boot partition is 100% used, not sure how to free up space here

Comment: all the other partitions have lot of space left, Can my /boot partition cause this issue, can you suggest how to add space to /boot

Comment: Please post the output of dpkg -l | grep linux-image

Comment: i had to clean up /boot manually and then i ran auto remove to fix it

Comment: "Clean up `/boot` manually...ran auto remove".. is the Bad way, and did NOT do what you think.  Please read http://askubuntu.com/questions/607594/why-is-it-unsafe-to-delete-old-kernels/607699